# Mule4 file write connector issue while writing file in src/main/resources

Tags: file, mule4

Trying to write JSON payload to the `src/main/resources` folder using Mule 4 write file connector, if I give working directory as `src/main/resources` and file name as `file.json`, it is trying to write in:

`D:\Deployment\anypoint-7\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.5.ee_7.3.1.201903081734\mule\bin\`

File should write in the `src/main/resources` project folder instead of the `plugin\runtime\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

It should contain the entire path.

> C:\ "your workspace" \ "project name" \src\main\resources\file.json

It is a better to have the address in connector-config and only the file name in the path. Though not mandatory, the connector config is need to avoid the below warning.

> WARN   [[MuleRuntime].io.04:
>   [multiplelookup].io@org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.LifecycleAwareConfigurationInstance.testConnectivity:186
>   @23d7d97e] [event: ]
>   org.mule.extension.file.internal.LocalFileConnectionProvider: File
>   connector 'config' does not specify the workingDir property.
>   Defaulting to 'C:\Users\yourUser'

Answer (score 0):

Your runtime is separate Java instance which runs in the D:\Deployment\anypoint-7\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.server.4.1.5.ee_7.3.1.201903081734\mule in your environment.

Runttime does not know about your Studio workspace. You have to specify real path to the place where you need to write files.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/FileNamesAndLocations.html